# Are Xbox One X Enhanced 'Play Anywhere' games seeing the same "Enhancements" on the PC?

Tags: xbox-one, windows-10

A few [Xbox One titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_One_X_Enhanced_games) are retroactively receiving updates to utilize the improved hardware of the newer Xbox One X.  ["Play Anywhere"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_Play_Anywhere_games) titles support cross-platform play on Windows 10.

Are the Windows 10 "Play Anywhere" versions of these games also receiving the same improvement updates as its Xbox One X counterparts?

Comment: This would likely be a case by case thing up to the developer, if at all.

Comment: I'm wondering if the PC version of these games don't need any enhancement, since you usually have more control over the graphics already.

Comment: They are improving these Xbox One titles with larger textures, HDR and Atmos support in some cases as well.  I don't think the PC titles are supporting these features. I'm curious if any of these new features are migrating to the PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not.
According to wiki, the "Enhanced games" are console specific patches that enable hdr/ add higher resolution/ improve performance all to match the more powerfull console.

[You can read up the entire definition here, with a list of features for each game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_One_X_enhanced_games)